# Why do I get java.lang.exception unrecognized body on routes with friend/authenticated as a wrapper?

Tags: clojure, compojure

I am using friend along with friend-redis-token where sessions are stored in redis for my compojure application.

for a route which is something like..

```
  (POST "/service/logout" {headers :headers}
          (session/invalidate-session
           (headers "x-auth-token")))
```

Everything works fine!

As soon as I wrap the handler with friend/authenticated.
I get the error

```
:WARN:oejs.AbstractHttpConnection:/service/logout
java.lang.Exception: Unrecognized body: ...
```

I am using the following middlewares:

```
                        (jsonware/wrap-json-body)
                        (jsonware/wrap-json-params)
                        (jsonware/wrap-json-response)
```

to convert everything in body to JSON, could that bve conflicting with friend ?

Comment: `jsonware` is what exactly?

Comment: its the ring middleware for json , i just renamed it to jsonware inside my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem might be with the return value of `session/invalidate-session`. So try something like this:

```
(POST "/service/logout" {headers :headers}
  (do (session/invalidate-session
        (headers "x-auth-token"))
      ""))
```

Compojure tries to be clever about doing the right thing with the return values of routes and this often ends up causing problems such as this.